# Translation exchange webapp (reward system, translating unrelated strings makes strangers translate your strings)

Tags: gratis, web-apps, translation, localization, crowdsourcing

I have a thousand strings and want them translated to Hindi.
I don´t want to pay money and I don't speak Hindi.

I am looking for a "translation exchange" platform:

- I translate unrelated strings into languages I know,
- **in exchange**, unrelated people translate my strings to Hindi.

I don't know exactly how this would work, but maybe I could get "credits" for performing translations that people want, and then place these credits on my strings. Or something similar. Maybe with the possibility to flag answers that seems bad, for fluent experienced users to check and act appropriately, a bit like moderation and tag-related privileges here on StackExchange.

**Important:** There **must** be a reward system that makes people translate my string after I have translated strings for others. Traditional translation crowdsourcing platforms like Crowdin/Transifex/TranslateWiki/Google Translator Toolkit are NOT valid answers.

Comment: Possible solution is http://lang-8.com/, but I´m not 100 per cent sure if you can translate that amount of strings there in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @Tobiask: lang-8 is for getting corrections, not for getting translations, right?

Comment: Perhaps https://translatewiki.net is what you are looking for.

Comment: @SVilcans: No it is not. Please read the "Important" paragraph above.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Ok, you could use Google Translator Toolkit and handle the rewards manually.

Comment: GTT does not have this concept of rewards. And in addition, that would not work, because the exchange is not 1-to-1. The exchange might involve several people, for instance: User1 translates en->fr and gets rewarded by User2 who uses credits he got by translating de->ja for User3.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul You´re right I guess... Have you checked out Amazon Mechanical Turk? But here you have to pay for the translation, just another kind of reward ;)

Comment: @Tobiask: It has to be free.

Comment: A new SE site... :)